# Assign Multi Dimensional Collection in PLSQL

Tags: collections, plsql, multidimensional-array, record

I have a record:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE rec01 IS OBJECT
( -- Business
   refund_desc VARCHAR2(20),
   percentage  VARCHAR2(5),
   amount      VARCHAR2(25),
   pmt_method  VARCHAR2(20)
)
```

And then I make the collection from that record

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tbl01 AS TABLE OF rec01
```

And then from that table I make another one collection

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tbl02 AS TABLE OF tbl01
```

How can I assign the value, for example value of tbl02(1)(2),.?
Better solution is using loop to assign it's value, but how,.?
thanks,.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155742/creating-or-simulating-two-dimensional-arrays-in-pl-sql

Answer (score 1):

Here is an  [`example`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm#i33997) of assigning value to a multilevel collection. Also check [`Here`](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=208).

These do not use Objects.