# How can I get the value of array inside an array in for loop ORACLE

Tags: arrays, oracle, loops, plsql, oracle8i

Can anyone help me how can I get the value of array inside an array in for loop ORACLE.
   This is a example IN PARAMETER Array. **I want to get the value of array is the array [3] in "ID" and VALUE of ID "EMP01658".**

Array
  (
    [1] => DC0001
    [2] => DC0002
    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => EMP01658
        )
   )

This is my PL SQL CODE;

**--This is my Package global variables**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_GLB_VARIABLES 
IS 

  TYPE refcursor        IS REF CURSOR;                        
  TYPE val_Array        IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(3000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
END;
```

**--This is my Procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proc_Array(
    param_Array     IN pkg_glb_variables.val_Array
)
IS

BEGIN
    for i in 1 .. param_Array.count
      loop
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('aRRay('||i||') :'||param_Array(i));

        IF param_Array(i)='Array' THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('UY MAY ISA PANG ARRAY!');
           for i_2 in 1 .. param_Array(i).count
             loop
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('aRRay('||i_2||') :'||param_Array(i_2));
             end loop;     
        END IF;
      end loop;  


END;
```

Thank you. :)

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you are asking.  Please show more complete code.

Comment: Hi sir, i just already edited it kindly check sir, thank you so much

Comment: Please see this question and answers: [Creating or simulating two dimensional arrays in PL/SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155742/creating-or-simulating-two-dimensional-arrays-in-pl-sql).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VARCHAR2 is not the same as an array (collection or PL/SQL table), and cannot be indexed as such.  You need to use Oracle's String functions.  Here is an example to print out each character of each varchar2 array element:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proc_Array(
    param_Array     IN pkg_glb_variables.val_Array
)
IS
vElement VARCHAR2(3000);
vLength  PLS_INTEGER;

BEGIN
    for i in 1 .. param_Array.count
      loop
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('aRRay('||i||') :'||param_Array(i));

        vElement := param_array(i);
        vLength  := length(vElement);

           for i_2 in 1 .. vLength
             loop
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('aRRay('||i_2||') :'||
                           substr(vElement,i_2,1) );
             end loop;     
      end loop;  
END;
```

A test to call the procedure:

```
declare
a   pkg_glb_variables.val_Array;
begin
  a(1) := 'HELLO';
  a(2) := 'goodbye';
  proc_array ( a );
end;
```

The resulting dbms_output:

```
my output - aRRay(1) :HELLO
my output - aRRay(1) :H
my output - aRRay(2) :E
my output - aRRay(3) :L
my output - aRRay(4) :L
my output - aRRay(5) :O
my output - aRRay(2) :goodbye
my output - aRRay(1) :g
my output - aRRay(2) :o
my output - aRRay(3) :o
my output - aRRay(4) :d
my output - aRRay(5) :b
my output - aRRay(6) :y
my output - aRRay(7) :e
```

Comment: BTW, please tell me you really aren't using 8i still?

Comment: Hey sir, Thanks for the answer , i will try this now. Haha, Yes sir, im still using Oracle 8i but im now uploading all my work in oracle 11g

Comment: **SAMPLE ARRAY:**

`Array ( [1] => DC0001 
        [2] => DC0002 
        [3] => Array ( 
                      [ID] => EMP01658 
               ) 
)`


Hello, Sir, hmm all i want to get the value of array is the array [3] in "ID" and VALUE of ID "EMP01658". Can you share me some trick to get the value of ID? I can't find another way to do that. Thank you again sir :)