# How to create a multidimensional array

Tags: sql, plsql

I am struggling a little understanding how this is done, and would really appreciate if someone could walk me through how a 2d array in PL/SQL is made?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating or simulating two dimensional arrays in PL/SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155742/creating-or-simulating-two-dimensional-arrays-in-pl-sql)

Comment: See [Multidimensional Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/composites.htm#LNPLS00507) from Oracle's [PL/SQL Collections and Records](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/composites.htm). There is three different examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of the following code as each row in table2 has a collection of type table1. You can insert any number of values as is shown in BEGIN.

```
DECLARE

TYPE table1 IS TABLE OF NUMBER 
  INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

TYPE table2 IS TABLE OF table1
  INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
var_i table2

BEGIN

var_i (1) (1) := 1;
var_i (1) (2) := 12;

END;
```