# Oracle PL/SQL How to create list of lists

Tags: oracle, list, plsql, collections

in python we create complex arrays like :

```
[['element1',['element2',['element3'],
['element1',['element2',['element3'],
['element1',['element2',['element3']]
```

is there anyway to do that in PL/SQL?

Comment: You can have collections of collections, or collections of object types which contain collectsions... you probably need to explain what you're actually trying to achieve though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155742/creating-or-simulating-two-dimensional-arrays-in-pl-sql

Answer (score 2):

You can use inheritance with Oracle types to have multiple nested collections:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE collect_abstract_type IS OBJECT(
  isCollection NUMBER(1,0),
  MEMBER FUNCTION toString RETURN CLOB
) NOT FINAL NOT INSTANTIABLE
/

CREATE TYPE collect_element_type UNDER collect_abstract_type (
  value VARCHAR2(20),
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION toString
    RETURN CLOB,
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION collect_element_type(value VARCHAR2)
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT
)
/

CREATE TYPE BODY collect_element_type AS
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION toString
    RETURN CLOB
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN '"' || SELF.value || '"';
  END;

  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION collect_element_type(value VARCHAR2)
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.isCollection := 0;
    SELF.value := value;
    RETURN;
  END;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE collect_abstract_type_table IS TABLE OF collect_abstract_type
/

CREATE TYPE collect_list_type UNDER collect_abstract_type (
  items collect_abstract_type_table,
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION toString
    RETURN CLOB,
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION collect_list_type
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION collect_list_type(items collect_abstract_type_table)
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT
)
/

CREATE TYPE BODY collect_list_type AS
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION toString
    RETURN CLOB
  IS
    p_string CLOB;
    p_first  BOOLEAN := TRUE;
  BEGIN
    p_string := '[';
    FOR i IN 1 .. SELF.items.count LOOP
      IF p_first THEN
        p_first := FALSE;
      ELSE
        p_string := p_string || ',';
      END IF;
      IF SELF.items(i) IS NULL THEN
        p_string := p_string || 'NULL';
      ELSE
        p_string := p_string || SELF.items(i).toString;
      END IF;      
    END LOOP;
    p_string := p_string || ']';
    RETURN p_string;
  END;

  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION collect_list_type
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.isCollection := 1;
    SELF.items := collect_abstract_type_table();
    RETURN;
  END;

  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION collect_list_type(items collect_abstract_type_table)
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.isCollection := 1;
    IF items IS NULL THEN
      SELF.items := collect_abstract_type_table();
    ELSE
      SELF.items := items;
    END IF;
    RETURN;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then you could do something like:

```
SELECT collect_list_type(
         collect_abstract_type_table(
           collect_element_type( 'Element1' ),
           collect_list_type(
             collect_abstract_type_table(
               collect_element_type( 'Element2' ),
               collect_list_type()
             )
           ),
           NULL,
           collect_element_type( 'Element4' )
         )
       ).toString() AS list
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

```
LIST
--------------------------------------------
["Element1",["Element2",[]],NULL,"Element4"]
```