# ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count ORA-06512 in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

i want to have 10 by 10 grid with numbers from 1 to 100
and it give me this error
ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count ORA-06512: at line 25

ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

i don't understand the error and i couldn't solve it
can someone please help me

```
DECLARE
    -- PL SQL code to create and fill a two-dimensional array
    -- create VARRAY type of 10 integers
    TYPE array_10_int  IS VARRAY(10) of PLS_INTEGER;

    -- create VARRAY type of array_10_int 
    TYPE grid_100_int IS VARRAY(10) of array_10_int;
    
    -- declare a variable of the grid_100_int type
    grid_var grid_100_int;
    
    -- declare counters 
    i PLS_INTEGER := 0;
    j PLS_INTEGER :=0;
    M PLS_INTEGER :=0;
    N PLS_INTEGER :=0;

BEGIN
    grid_var := grid_100_int();
    -- TO DO : use nested loop to fill grid_var with numbers 1- 100
    /** YOUR CODE HERE **/
    M:=0;
    Loop
        M:=M+1;
        N:=0;
        LOOP
           J:=j+1;
            If grid_var(M)(N)<100 THEN
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(' ' || grid_var(M)(N) || ' ');
            ELSE
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( grid_var(M)(N) || ' ');
            END IF;
            
            EXIT WHEN (N =100);
        END LOOP;
        dbms_output.put_line(' ');
        EXIT WHEN (M=10);
    END LOOP;
    

-- Print the grid with nested loop
    i:=0;
    LOOP --outer loop
        i := i+1;
        j := 0;
        LOOP    -- inner loop
            j:= j+1;
            IF grid_var(i)(j) < 10 THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(' ' || grid_var(i)(j) || ' ');
            ELSE
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( grid_var(i)(j) || ' ');
            END IF;
           
            EXIT WHEN (j =10);
        END LOOP;
        dbms_output.put_line(' ');
        EXIT WHEN (i =10);
    END LOOP;    
    
    
END;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating or simulating two dimensional arrays in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155742/creating-or-simulating-two-dimensional-arrays-in-pl-sql)

Comment: You use `j` in first loop, but `n` remains the same. The code should run forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***A second look.***  
Creating multiple dimensional arrays (10 x 10) are tricky things. They are actually a collection of a collection. Further, each has the same definition and existence requirements: the element must exist before referenced, either by `extend` or `array initialization`. The following initializes each array before referencing it. Also it uses a [FOR loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS) letting Postgres handle the setting, incrementing subscripts and loop exiting, rather than manually.  See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f45d0a2451bfd5ff34daa9d0885b2e2d).

```
declare
    -- PL SQL code to create and fill a two-dimensional array
    -- create VARRAY type of 10 integers
    type array_10_int  is varray(10) of pls_integer;  

    -- create VARRAY type of array_10_int 
    type grid_100_int is varray(10) of array_10_int ;  
    
    -- declare a variable of the grid_100_int type
    grid_var grid_100_int;
begin

    grid_var := grid_100_int(null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);  -- initialize outer array 
    -- TO DO : use nested loop to fill grid_var with numbers 1- 100
    /* YOUR CODE HERE */
    
    for m in 1 .. 10 
    loop 
        grid_var(m) := array_10_int(null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null); -- initialize the inner array   
        for n in 1 .. 10 
        loop                                  
            grid_var(m)(n) := 10*(m-1)+ n;   
        end loop ; 
    end loop; 
 
-- Print the grid with nested loop
      for m in 1 .. 10 
      loop
         for n in 1 .. 10 
         loop 
            dbms_output.put_line ('grid_var(' || to_char(m) 
                                 || ')(' || to_char(n) 
                                 || ') = ' || to_char(grid_var(m)(n))
                                 );    
        end loop ;   
    end loop; 
    
end;
```

**Take away:** Creating and using multiple dimensional arrays in Oracle is doable. `But use them only when there is no other option.` They add considerable complexity, usually unnecessary, and are poorly understood.  (The above one is vary simple.)  
**Take away 2** Let Postgres control your loops. Less error prone, less code, easier to read.

---

PL/SQL array index begin with 1. But in the following code the local variable `n` is 0 when first used as an index.

```
 Loop
        M:=M+1;
        N:=0;
        LOOP
           J:=j+1;
            If grid_var(M)(N)<100 THEN    --<<< n is 0 which throws your  exception.
                ... 
               EXIT WHEN (N =100);   --<<< NEVER occurs, N is not
```

Unfortunately, this is not your only issue (in this logic). You exit statement is condition `EXIT WHEN (N =100);` will never be met. You initialize the variable `n` before entering the loop, but never increment it in the loop.
Adjust the above to:

```
    Loop
                M:=M+1;
                N:=1;          -- <<< change here 
                LOOP
                   J:=j+1;
                    If grid_var(M)(N)<=100 THEN 
                    ... 
                   EXIT WHEN (N >100);   --<<< NEVER occurs, N is not incremented in the loop;
                END LOOP;
```

Your other loop does not appear to have the same issue, but you should check it.